# How to Group Element in Javascript to get the Cartesian product in javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, cartesian-product

I have a scenario where I have an object just like this.

```
   [
    {attributeGroupId:2, attributeId: 11, name: 'Diamond'}
    {attributeGroupId:1, attributeId: 9, name: '916'}
    {attributeGroupId:1, attributeId: 1, name: '24K'}
    {attributeGroupId:2, attributeId: 12, name: 'Square'}
]
```

Expected result:

```
[
    {attributeGroupId:2, attributeId: 11, name: 'Diamond'},
    {attributeGroupId:2, attributeId: 12, name: 'Square'}
]
```

,

```
[
    {attributeGroupId:1, attributeId: 9, name: '916'},
    {attributeGroupId:1, attributeId: 1, name: '24K'}
]
```

So I can make the cartesian product of it just like this,

```
[
     {attributeId: 11-9, name: 'Diamond-916'}, 
     {attributeId: 11-1, name: 'Diamond-24K'},
     {attributeId: 12-9, name: 'Square-916'}, 
     {attributeId: 12-1, name: 'Square-24K'},
]
```

Now I want to keep this logic as generic as possible as the number of attributeGroupId is not known during runtime.

I think that splitting the array into multiple smaller array on the basis of attributeGroupId should be the first step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a basic filter function like this:

```
function filterForAttributeGroupId(data, id) {
  return data.filter((item) => item.attributeGroupId === id);
}

console.log(filterForAttributeGroupId(data, 1)) //contains all elements with attributeGroupId = 1
console.log(filterForAttributeGroupId(data, 2)) //contains all elements with attributeGroupId = 2
```

Here you have a generic solution returning an array of filtered Arrays:

```
function filterForAttributeGroupId(data) {
  const mem = {};
  data.forEach((item) => {
    if ( mem[item.attributeGroupId] ) {
      mem[item.attributeGroupId].push(item);
    } else {
      mem[item.attributeGroupId] = [item];
    }
  })
  return Object.values(mem);
}
```

**Edit after feedback from comment**
If the order of concatenated attributes does not matter, you can use the following code to get the "cartesian concatenation" of n different arrays:

```
function cartesianProduct(arrays) {
  if (arrays.length <= 1 ) return arrays[0];
  const first = arrays[0];
  const second = cartesianProduct(arrays.slice(1));
  const result =  [];
   first.forEach(( itemFirst ) => {
      second.forEach( (itemSecond) => {
        result.push({attributeId: `${itemFirst.attributeId}-${itemSecond.attributeId}`, name: `${itemFirst.name}-${itemSecond.name}`})
      });
   });
   return result;
}
```

This way calling the following:

```
console.log(cartesianProduct(filterForAttributeGroupId(data)));
```

results in the expected data (although the strings are concatenated in another order):

```
[
  {
    "attributeId":"9-11",
    "name":"916-Diamond"
  },
  {
    "attributeId":"9-12",
    "name":"916-Square"
  },
  {
    "attributeId":"1-11",
    "name":"24K-Diamond"
  },
  {
    "attributeId":"1-12",
    "name":"24K-Square"
  }
]
```

Comment: This was helpful however, the attributeGroupId is dynamic, as it could contain n numbers. I want something that would make a group of these common attributeGroupId

Comment: Do you mean you want to have an array containing all "subarrays", each one being filtered on a different attributeGroupId?

Comment: Yes and then I want to make a cartesian product out of that subarrays

Comment: I adjusted my answer. Can you check if this is what you are searching for?

Comment: And then I can I apply Cartesian product on them? By Cartesian product I just want to make a new object each containing a hyphen deliminated like name = Diamond-24K

Comment: You can. The only problem I see in this case is, that you want to concatenate strings and the order of this concatenation matters. This information is not yet present in the returned array. Is there any rule in which order you want to concatenate these strings?

Comment: No I want to make a combination and pass it to the backend so they could split the string and get the value

Comment: Please check if my edited answer matches your expectations.

Comment: This above logic is good for finding Cartesian product of two arrays. However, in my situation the number of array could increase as the user could enter more attribute-groups. I think here we should use Recursion so as to make the solution more flexible.

Comment: Well, I used recursion to handle any amount of attribute-groups. What exactly did not work here?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to break this logic into pieces.  First, a cartesian product function for an array of arrays seems very useful.  So let's make a utility function for that.  Second, breaking an array into subarrays based on some shared feature is also common.  So let's make a second one for that.

Then we can write a simple main function which groups the id by `attributeGroupId`, and calls the cartesian product on that, then for each item in the resulting array like

```
[
  {attributeGroupId: 2, attributeId: 11, name: "Diamond"},
  {attributeGroupId: 1, attributeId: 9, name: "916"}
]
```

We can create a new object by combining the `attributeId` and `name` properties

```js
const cartesian = ([xs, ...xss]) =>
  xs == undefined ? [[]] : xs .flatMap (x => cartesian (xss) .map (ys => [x, ...ys]))

const group = (fn, k) => (xs) => Object .values (xs .reduce (
  (a, x) => ((k = 'x' + fn (x)), (a [k] = a [k] || []), (a [k] .push (x)), a), {}
))

const regroupAtts = (xs) => 
  cartesian (group (x => x .attributeGroupId) (xs))
    .map (xs => ({
      attributeId: xs .map (x => x .attributeId) .join ('-'),
      name: xs .map (x => x.name) .join ('-')
    }))

const atts = [{attributeGroupId: 2, attributeId: 11, name: 'Diamond'}, {attributeGroupId: 1, attributeId: 9, name: '916'}, {attributeGroupId: 1, attributeId: 1, name: '24K'}, {attributeGroupId: 2, attributeId: 12, name: 'Square'}]
const atts2 = [{attributeGroupId: 2, attributeId: 11, name: 'Diamond'}, {attributeGroupId: 1, attributeId: 9, name: '916'}, {attributeGroupId: 3, attributeId: 101, name: 'foo'}, {attributeGroupId: 1, attributeId: 1, name: '24K'}, {attributeGroupId: 3, attributeId: 102, name: 'bar'}, {attributeGroupId: 2, attributeId: 12, name: 'Square'}, {attributeGroupId: 3, attributeId: 103, name: 'baz'}]


console .log ('Original:', regroupAtts (atts))
console .log ('With third group added:', regroupAtts (atts2))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We add a third attribute with entries of name `"foo"`, `"bar"`, and `"baz"` to show how this extends to more attributes.  Of course, you'll have to consider combinatorial explosions if you add too many such attributes, but the code is designed to handle it.

And interesting abstraction from here is if you wanted to parameterize the names `"attributeGroupId"`, `"attributeId"`, and `"name"`.  We might choose to do this:

```
const regroup = (key, props) => (xs) => 
  cartesian (group (x => x [key]) (xs))
    .map (xs => Object .fromEntries (
      props .map (prop => [prop, xs .map (x => x [prop]) .join ('-')])
    ))

const regroupAtts = regroup ('attributeGroupId', ['attributeId', 'name'])
```

```js
const cartesian = ([xs, ...xss]) =>
  xs == undefined ? [[]] : xs .flatMap (x => cartesian (xss) .map (ys => [x, ...ys]))

const group = (fn, k) => (xs) => Object .values (xs .reduce (
  (a, x) => ((k = 'x' + fn (x)), (a [k] = a[k] || []), (a[k] .push (x)), a), {}
))

const regroup = (key, props) => (xs) => 
  cartesian (group (x => x [key]) (xs))
    .map (xs => Object .fromEntries (
      props .map (prop => [prop, xs .map (x => x [prop]) .join ('-')])
    ))

const regroupAtts = regroup ('attributeGroupId', ['attributeId', 'name']) 


const atts = [{attributeGroupId: 2, attributeId: 11, name: 'Diamond'}, {attributeGroupId: 1, attributeId: 9, name: '916'}, {attributeGroupId: 1, attributeId: 1, name: '24K'}, {attributeGroupId: 2, attributeId: 12, name: 'Square'}]
const atts2 = [{attributeGroupId: 2, attributeId: 11, name: 'Diamond'}, {attributeGroupId: 1, attributeId: 9, name: '916'}, {attributeGroupId: 3, attributeId: 101, name: 'foo'}, {attributeGroupId: 1, attributeId: 1, name: '24K'}, {attributeGroupId: 3, attributeId: 102, name: 'bar'}, {attributeGroupId: 2, attributeId: 12, name: 'Square'}, {attributeGroupId: 3, attributeId: 103, name: 'baz'}]

console .log ('Original:', regroupAtts (atts))
console .log ('With third group added:', regroupAtts (atts2))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

In writing it this way, we now have reusable `cartesian` and `group` functions, which appear often.  In fact, I stole those from previous answers I've written.  (I did alter `group` a bit by adding the `'x' +` to the key generation.  This is because your keys (`attributeGroupId`s) are simple numbers.  When `Object.values` iterates an object like that, it does so by doing those first, *in numeric order*, then iterates the remaining String keys in insertion order, then the Symbols.  By prepending a string, I make this all into insertion order, and get back the order you preferred.  I'm trying to figure out if this variant of the function replaces the one in my usual toolbox.)